# iPhone: SHA1 hash on ios 4.3

Tags: iphone, hash, sha1

I'm using the following function for SHA1 hash from NSString in my application:

```
-(NSString *)stringToSha1:(NSString *)str{
    const char *cstr = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:str.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;

}
```

This works like a charm on my iphone devices with ios 5.0 and up, but on my iPad running version 4.3.5 it crashes on the line

```
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
```

It says the following:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol _CC_SHA1 in
>    because dependent dylib #3 could not be loaded
>
> dyld: can't resolve symbol _CC_SHA1 in  because dependent dylib #3 could not be loaded

Any ideas on how to make it work on my iPad 4.3.5 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself, though i have no idea why it worked.

Removed the Framework "libcommonCrypto.dylib" from my project, clean, build and it worked.

Tested on IOS 4.1 and 4.3, works like a charm.

Comment: If this works as a solution then go ahead and mark it as the answer, even if it is your own.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the header file you'll see:

```
extern unsigned char *CC_SHA1(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_4, __IPHONE_5_0);
```

The `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(...)` stuff means that this function is only available on OS X 10.4+ and iOS 5.0+. This is why your application is crashing.

Comment: Yea i've seen that. On the other hand, several places they say it should work for 4.3 nontheless, so it is very strange :\ See here for one of several examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971827/are-cc-md5-and-cc-sha1-available-in-ios-4